# Targeting popular keywords for Google Ads and less popular keywords for Google search

Tags: seo, keywords, google-ads, ad-targeting

I'm a web and mobile app developer with some SEO experience but I'm certainly not an expert. Lately I've been putting more thought into our property management website's SEO, and specifically keyword targeting. What I'm struggling with is whether I should be targeting popular keywords which have high competition, e.g. "property management software", or less popular "long tail" keywords, e.g. "property management apps for android", that have lower competition.

Targeting popular keywords seems more beneficial for when I'm running Google Ads campaigns, as I can run the ads on these popular keywords and get a lot of impressions and clicks. However, for actual Google searches and ignoring ads, I'll have no chance to compete with the bigger property management sites on the popular keywords so the effort goes to waste.

On the flip side, targeting less popular keywords seems more beneficial for actual Google searches because the competition is low and I might actually get some traffic. However, when I run Google Ads campaigns on these keywords I get very little results because there aren't enough monthly searches to actually generate any substantial traffic. And if I target less popular keywords but then run Google Ads on the popular keywords, the Ad keywords get marked with a low quality score because they don't match up with my website content.

So what is the solution here? Have separate pages that target popular keywords vs. less popular keywords? If I do that then I end up with duplicate versions of my pages, which isn't very useful to end users. It also means I'm in a pickle when it comes to site navigation, as I need to link to both versions to get better SEO results (I read 3+ internal links to each page is a must) but that's confusing to users if they see links to separate variations of the same page.